# google cloud sdk :failed to install, ImportError, DLL load failed

Tags: python, sdk, cloud, importerror

I tried to install and requirements was python 2.7.9 , i have same version(and can't up to 15 even 10), i have w8.1 64 and python 32bits
I search how to pass the installer because it says in the image a abstract of installer logs:
[paste of installer logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/931QM.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Ok as i said arch of python and win is not the same and google probably give the detected arch for the download:

I will try restart if its the environement variables else i ll try manual install with 32 bits from here
[Install sdk cloud](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/downloads?authuser=2&hl=fr)

[One of the first error line reported persist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjqOt.jpg)